# share post blogger to specific number on whatsapp

Tags: blogger

I have a blogger blog (cart). I want to add a share button to the post. It brings the link of the post to my number on WhatsApp to complete the sale can any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code, just change +120XXXXX126 to your own number, this should be used somewhere near `<data:post.body/>`

```xml
<a expr:href='"https://api.whatsapp.com/send" params {text: data:post.url, phone: "+120XXXXX126"}' target='_blank'>
    send to Whatsapp
</a>
```